# I Want to Disable the Domain License Section

Tags: php, laravel

I did some coding and produced domain licensed code. I want to use this code in my different domain now, but I am encountering an error. How can I disable the domain license section?

```
             }
            }
            return $ViewData;
        } catch (\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException $ex) {
            return abort(404);
        }
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $LisansFile = base_path("vendor/bin/system.json");
        $HataSayfasi = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"tr\"><head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"> <title>Lisans Hatası</title> <style> * { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; } html { scroll-behavior: smooth; } p { line-height: 25px; } h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color: #424a52; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 600; line-height: 25px; } h2 { font-size: 18px; } body { background-color: #F1F5F9; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(98, 108, 119); } .container { width: 550px; margin: auto; } .box { width: 100%; border: 1px solid #E2E8F0; background-color: #fff; overflow: hidden; display: block; } .header { width: 100%; margin-top: 100px; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap; display: flex; } .br-4, .btn, .box { -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; } .p-20 { padding: 20px; } .mt-20 { margin-top: 20px; } .mt-40 { margin-top: 40px; } .mb-10 { margin-bottom: 10px; } .btn { width: fit-content; height: 45px; padding: 0px 15px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: 700;; border: none; cursor: pointer; outline: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; background: rgb(235, 121, 39); transition: 200ms; color: #fff; align-items: center; justify-content: center; display: flex; } .btn>* { pointer-events: none; } .btn:hover { box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0/20%) 0 2px 4px, rgb(0 0 0/16%) 0 7px 13px -3px, rgb(0 0 0/30%) 0 -3px 0 inset; } .bg-black { background-color: rgb(66, 74, 82); } .w-100 { width: 100%; } </style></head><body> <div class=\"container\"> <div class=\"header\"> <img src=\"sssss.com\" alt=\"XXXXX\"> </div> <div class=\"box p-20 mt-40\"> <h2 class=\"w-100 mb-10\" style=\"text-align: center;\">Lisans Bilgileri Hatalı</h2> <p>Üzgünüz, mevcut domain adresiniz için <b>lisans anahtarınızın yanlış</b> olduğunu belirtmek isteriz. Bu durum, alan adınızın düzgün çalışmasını engelleyebilir ve çeşitli sorunlara yol açabilir. Sorunsuz bir web varlığı sürdürebilmek için lisans anahtarınızı güncellemeniz veya yeni bir lisans satın almanız gerekebilir....</p> </div> <a href=\"https://sssss.com\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"btn bg-black w-100 mt-20\">Hemen Lisans Satın Al</a> </div></body></html>";
        if (file_exists($LisansFile)) {
            $MevcutKey = file_get_contents($LisansFile);
            $SiteUrl = preg_replace("#^https?://#", "", getenv("HTTP_HOST"));
            $SiteUrl = preg_replace("#^www\\.#", "", $SiteUrl);
            $SiteUrl = preg_replace("#/\$#", "", $SiteUrl);
            $SiteUrlHash = sha1(strrev(sha1(md5(sha1(base64_encode(sha1(md5(base64_encode(md5(sha1(md5(md5(sha1(md5(md5(sha1($SiteUrl . date("Ymd"))))))))))))))))));
            $LisansHash = wordwrap(strtoupper($SiteUrlHash), 5, "-", true);
            if ($LisansHash != $MevcutKey) {
                $LisansBilgileri = \App\Models\Frontend\FirmaBilgileri_Model::FirmaBilgileriGetir(["LisansKey"], [["FirmaBilgiId", 1]]);
                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sssss.com");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/json"]);
                $FormData = ["SiteAdresi" => $SiteUrl, "LisansKey" => $LisansBilgileri["LisansKey"]];
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($FormData));
                $jsonData = curl_exec($curl);
                $response = json_decode($jsonData, true);
                curl_close($curl);
                if (isset($response["Status"]) && $response["Status"] == "error") {
                    echo $HataSayfasi;
                    exit;
                }
                file_put_contents($LisansFile, $LisansHash);
            }
        } else {
            echo $HataSayfasi;
            exit;
        }
    }
    protected function hesabim_form_valid($Request, $KullaniciId = 0)
    {
        $Roles = ["Ad" => "required", "Soyad" => "required", "Telefon" => "required|string|min:11", "EMail" => "required|email|unique:kullanicilar,EMail," . $KullaniciId . ",KullaniciId", "UyelikTipi" => "required", "Adres" => "required"];
```

Comment: Probably you can just remove the curl request

Comment: how will I do? When I delete this code from the lines the error persists

Comment: It would help if you posted details of the error

Comment: 500 SERVER ERROR I get an error. I can enter the admin panel, but the frontend part is like this

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging, diagnosing or resolving problems. You need to check the error logs on the server (or enable on-screen error reporting, if it's a development environment) to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem, and then moving on to trying to fix it.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use lexical variable $message as a parameter name in /public_html/app-6602de0a4df9b/app/Http/Controllers/Frontend/Frontend.php on line 1935

Comment: Ok. That doesn't seem to be anything to do with the code you've shown here. There is no $message variable in the code you provided.

Comment: What causes the problem? There is no problem when Ioncube is encrypted. Ioncube gives an error when I use it without a password.

Comment: All I can tell is that you Cannot use lexical variable $message as a parameter name! Without a [mre] of the issue, nobody can help you. We can't see the code which is related to the issue. It's not clear to me what the involvement of ionCube would be - you didn't really explain the context either. But none of this is related to the question you originally asked. I suggest you start a new question about this different problem.